# Python check if website status ok,and return the response time

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to test if the website status and return the requested time and response code at the same time.

```py
requests.head('http://www.google.com').elapsed.total_seconds()
```

this code just return the requested time

```py
requests.head('http://www.google.com').elapsed.total_seconds()
```

i want get the response code like 200 or 404, and the requested time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the response code, and the total elapsed time, you can do this:

```
f = requests.head('http://www.google.com')
```

Now to see the response code you can just look at `f.status_code` and to see the time, use `f.elapsed.total_seconds()`

Comment: Standard disclaimer: not all URLs respond to a head request with the same status code as they would for the equivalent get